# IE7: Nested inline elements are causing parent to act like block

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a link that I've styled with an icon and a border to look like a button. It's working fine in all browsers except IE7. The bordered `<a>` tag is expanding to fill the width of its parent — it's acting like a block. If I remove the icon, the `<b>` tag, it's fine.

Notes: Both `<a>` and `<b>` have display: inline-block, which should be supported in Exploder 7 since they're naturally inline elements. I tried giving them the standard fix (zoom: 1, display: inline;) in my ie7 stylesheet anyways. No luck.
I've tried every zoom, position, and display combination I can think of; I've looked through all kinds of posts; any help is MUCH appreciated!

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aF894/

Comment: I'd avoid using the b tag all together. There's no reason to use these old styling tags anymore. Use a span if you just need something to hook into or use <strong> instead of <b>

Comment: Thanks — my b tag is not semantic, it's just holding the background image for the icon. I use `<b>` cause it's shorter than `<span>`. I tried substituting span, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `text-index: -9999px;` will get it to work.

IE7 had some oddities with the margins that you'll need to account for to get it to display in IE7 like the other browsers. However that should be handled in a separate style sheet which it looks like you have.

Will still work in other browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/aF894/8/

Comment: Thanks — I would never have checked that property! It's not working yet, but I'm finding some other threads on text-indent problems for IE7 so I'll see if there's some other thing I'm missing.

Comment: If you can post some more of the actual code you're using someone can probably help. The example in jsfiddler is functioning. What is the reason for the text-indent?

Comment: The text-indent is to hide the icon character and display the image. (Phark method, http://css-tricks.com/630-css-image-replacement/) — will edit the post to add a link to the staging server.

Comment: Ahh. May want to try either instead directly add the image via img tag or a different method. It may be that one of the other CSS properties are conflicting.

Comment: Bingo — another float:right on that `<b>` tag was causing the problem. Removing that, and the text-indent, and it's good! Thanks!